# Installation error when running code with activity-alias

Tags: android, launching-application

I have used activity alias to show multiple app icons as per condition. The code is working fine but when I run the code in debug mode via usb directly it gives the below installation error :

```
Error while executing: am start -n "com.****.****/com.****.****.splashscreen.SplashScreen" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -D
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.****.****/.splashscreen.SplashScreenpinkathon }
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {com.****.****/com.****.****.splashscreen.SplashScreenpinkathon} does not exist.

Error while Launching activity
```

Comment: Simple solution is just **`invalid-cache and restart android studio`**

Comment: Tried this, but it does not work

Comment: @ParthAnjaria Did you find any solution for it?

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue-- Android Studio's default launch option when debugging is "Default Activity," which picks the Activity or activity-alias based on your AndroidManifest.xml. If your app disables the default activity-alias, the next time you launch debugger won't be able to launch.

My work around for this was to change the Android Studio Run/Debug configurations to pick the Activity that the aliases target:

Run -> Edit Configurations -> Launch Options -> Change "Launch" to "Specified Activity", specify the target activity in "Activity"